# Importing area attributes from one shapefile into another grid shapefile?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I have two shapefiles of same extent. One is a shapefile of tree canopy coverage with the area attribute. The other shapefile is 20m*20m grids of the same area, now I have to import the canopy coverage information into the grid shapefile attribute. Note that the canopy coverage is falling in multiple grids but i need to clip out the information falling exactly within the grids.

[image: Grids and the tree canopy shapefile]

I have tried with spatial join but the issue is with the canopy sizes the tool uses intersection which is selecting whole canopy layer which is falling in multiple grids. I need to get the clipped area information within each grid.

Comment: You've been here a while, but haven't yet taken the [Tour], which explains how Questions should only ask one question. By tagging this with two GIS packages,  you're effectively asking two questions.

Comment: Union and Summary Statistics? Alternatively, ArcGIS Pro has a tool call "Summarize Within" that will do what you are after.

Comment: ArcGIS: Make feature layer with ratio policy on desired fields, then intersect

Answer (score 2):

Intersect canopy shapefile with grid shapefile, this will divide the canopy polygons as per the grid coverage. Now recalculate the area of the polygons (shapefile generated after the intersection) that were generated using intersect operation. Finally, apply spatial join operation on the grid file to join the area and other attributes of the intersecting canopy polygons. This solution may be time taking but I hope it will solve your problem.

If intersect operation results in multiple polygons within a single grid or cell, then, first dissolve them based on the attributes of grid shapefile. Then recalculate area and apply spatial join operation.

Comment: Thank you Mayank, for the suggestion, it worked. Sorry for the late response. Cheers!

Comment: @amit, You're welcome. Please accept it as the answer to your question.